# Curl doesn't get external websites

Tags: php, linux, apache, curl

I have some troubles with cUrl configuration on my local machine (my own computer).

I can only download site that is placed on localhost. Trying any other host causes failure (empty string returned). I'm sure that code is ok - it works on my production server.

Also, `curl_errno` doesn't return any error.

I can't find the problem, please help.

Edit: Here's the code.

```
<?php
$url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch); // It's empty
```

Comment: Failure: empty string returned.

John, code isn't the problem as I said, but as you wish, I'll paste it into question.

Comment: Print out curl_error() http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php and show us what it says. Curl does not spit out errors automatically, you have to fetch them. Whenever I am using curl and things aren't working right that's the first thing I do, spit out curl_error(), and that almost always points me to the issue.

Comment: Verv, it returns nothing - because there is no error as I pointed in question.

Comment: Check whether you system's firewall allows Apache to access internet or not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is PHP curl installed on your machine, if not then install it first and then try

for installation you may use either of these methods

- http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php
- sudo apt-get install php5-curl - and then restart apache.

it should work

Comment: when he says it works for localhost, then it means it's installed

Comment: na he's saying its working on production, and not on his localhost "  I'm sure that code is ok - it works on my production server. "

Comment: he said: **I can only download site that is placed on localhost.** which means the thing I said :-D

Comment: Aaah! my bad, lets find a solution for him

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try this instead of curl

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$url = "http://stackoverflow.com";

echo file_get_contents($url);
```

also make sure that allow_url_fopen is turned on in php.ini
http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: I need to use Curl, so this isn't a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Echo** the result ! **[Tested and works]**

```
<?php
$url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $result;//Added
```

Comment: It was once proposed and it's author agreed to delete it. Code snippet I have added doesn't contain result printing.